# React document.addEventListener fire immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I have search about this problem.

It must be pass function reference.

`document.addEventListener("click", () => {}, false)`

But what I do is still fire immediately.

Do I make some wrong?

**Test code is below**

```
export default function App() {
  const start = () => {
    console.log("start");
  };
  const click1 = () => {
    document.addEventListener("click", start);
  };

  const click2 = () => {
    const element = document.getElementById("p");
    element.addEventListener("click", start);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      <button onClick={click1}>Click1</button>
      <hr />

      <p id="p">123</p>
      <button onClick={click2}>Click2</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// Click1 -  immediately, problem here

// Click2 - no immediately
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-grass-5fok7b?file=/src/App.js

**What I expect**

click first, add click event, **no** anything is log.

click second,  log `'start'`

**actually output**

click first, add click event, log `start`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're handling a [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) with your `onClick` handler and adding a native event listener at the `document` level. Adding the listener will complete before the event bubbles up to the top therefore you also see it execute for the original event.

If you don't want that to happen, stop the event from bubbling

```js
const click1 = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  document.addEventListener("click", start);
};
```

[image: Edit great-flower-cc31dy]

---

FYI, you should also remove the DOM listener when your component unmounts

```js
useEffect(() => () => document.removeEventListener("click", start), []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option you might consider, keeping in mind the React paradigm to only attach listeners using React when possible, would be to attach the click handler to your App, rather than to the document with `.addEventListener`. (Best to only use `addEventListener` when there's no alternative with React handlers.)

```js
function App() {
  const [started, setStarted] = React.useState(false);
  const tryLog = () => {
    if (started) {
      log();
    }
  };
  const log = () => console.log("event");
  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={tryLog}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      <button onClick={() => setStarted(true)}>Click1</button>
      <hr />

      <p id="p">123</p>
      <button onClick={log}>Click2</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```